# Disable textboxes depending on the value of another textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I got three textboxes in my Form. My goal is to disable the validate and evaluate textbox if the number in digit textbox is not equal to 0. How do i accomplish this?

**Pseudo code**

```
if(digit.Text != 0 )
{
  validate.enable = false;
  evaluate.enable = false;
}
else
{
  validate.enable = true;
  evaluate.enable = true;
}
```

**My Attempt**

```js
function disableME()
{
  var numberTextBox = document.getElementById('number'),
      validateTextBox = document.getElementById('validate'),
      evaluateTextBox = document.getElementById('evaluate');

  if (numberTextBox.value != 0) 
  {
    validateTextBox.disable = true;
    evaluateTextBox.disable = true;
  }
  else
  {
    validateTextBox.disable = false;
    evaluateTextBox.disable = false;     
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="welcome.php" method="post" id="myForm">
  Number: <input type="number" id="number" onchange="disableME()"><br>
  Validate: <input type="text" id="validate" onchange="disableME()"><br>
  Evaluate: <input type="text" id="evaluate" onchange="disableME()"><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ELEMENT.disabled` instead of `ELEMENT.disable`.

Here is the change to your code:

```js
function disableME()
{
  var numberTextBox = document.getElementById('number'),
      validateTextBox = document.getElementById('validate'),
      evaluateTextBox = document.getElementById('evaluate');

  if (numberTextBox.value != 0) 
  {
    validateTextBox.disabled = true;
    evaluateTextBox.disabled = true;
  }
  else
  {
    validateTextBox.disabled = false;
    evaluateTextBox.disabled = false;     
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="welcome.php" method="post" id="myForm">
  Number: <input type="number" id="number" onchange="disableME()"><br>
  Validate: <input type="text" id="validate" onchange="disableME()"><br>
  Evaluate: <input type="text" id="evaluate" onchange="disableME()"><br>
</form>
```